# Is labeling my button as "Back" too general?

Tags: buttons, user-expectation, users, dashboard

I have an application that has a variety of different panels on it (similar to a dashboard of sorts) and I'm struggling with how to inform my users about a specific `Back` button and how to label it.

Currently, this portion of the dashboard looks something like this:

[image: Basic Layout]

There are summary stats at the top, then various types of charts below it. When the user clicks on a specific sale (the main table), they will get specific statistics related to that sale. When the user clicks once, the layout becomes this:

[image: Layout Two]

The back button only controls the statistics panel, so if the user clicks `Back`, it will take them back to the `Summary Stats`. The table of sales won't change and the charts on the bottom won't change. How do I:

1. Let my user's know that the `Back` button exists and
2. Make sure they understand that it only applies to the `Summary Stats` panel and not the whole application

Will users intuitively know that the `Back` button is referring to the stats panel or do I need to give them more direction and label it something like `Back to Summary Stats`?

Comment: Mobile? Why not use a pop out chart(s) and then a close button to close the popped out charts?

Comment: Nope. It's going to be a desktop application and this will be a column on the right hand side of the dashboard.

Comment: Why not just to "Back to Summary Stats" that way it's not ambiguous. Additionally, it'll be associated with that page because it won't show on another page, correct?

Comment: @Majo0od I had that originally, but it takes up much more space than I'd like it to. The title and button start to run together and it doesn't look good

Comment: Fair enough mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to test it out but I believe that one of these buttons would more clearly communicate the described action to the user...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that might work is to use tabs which mark the **Summary Stats** rectangle...

[image: tab1]

then automatically switch context over to **Specific Stats** as needed in your example above but leaving a clear way back for the user...

[image: tab2]

Comment: This solution will only work if you have a default set of Specific Stats to show which I highly recommend.  If hitting the "Back" button makes me lose the list of Specific Stats with no way back then that could be frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I am feeling lucky : 
How about a simple arrow icons (<) on the right hand side or as an icon on the left (Back icon) Specific Stats . Nicely done visually.  Instead of even writing Back. I feel its pretty clear even if users did this once.

I think "Back to Summary" is ok. (are you having space and visual clutter issues then my suggestion is don't try this)

I am not in favor of hovering. If the user wants to pay attention to the detail info it quickly becomes annoying. Some users may not be dexterous enough.

Comment: Yes to the visual clutter issues. My problem is the button is running into the title if I put `Back to Summary` or `Back to Summary Stats`

Answer (score 0):

Labeling the button "back" may be general but that's the ***appropriate*** label.

> From your description, "Summary stats" and "Charts" are not related
>   with each other.

In this case you can consider a separation between them like the below.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHPG2Q.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

*In these cases the user will know that the "back" button will refresh only the stats and not the charts. Also you can have the button as "back" itself.*

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a pop-over that has a 'close' button for the detail view.

Otherwise, if it's purely desktop, could hovering the table data expose the detail info?

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? Why would you suggest such a modification, and how would moving to a hover in the case of desktop improve the UX? Good answers point to existing precedence, research and/or studies.